# Cannot remove class from div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a class on a div and then delete it. First I thought just do like I did before with toggleClass, but that doesn't seem to work, because I'm adding a class to an *ID* instead of a *Class*. I want my header to have a black background top as well with the class: **headerbg.**

Also I have a small question about the color of my hamburger menu. I wanted to have a toggle for colors of the white lines (orange instead of white) on the class when pressed on the hamburger menu.

[My live version where it is on, works only when 1024px or smaller](http://larsdejonge.nl/bootstrap/aboutnew.html)

**My Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hamburger").click(function(){
        $(".hamburger").toggleClass("closed");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
        $("header").addClass('headerbg');              
    });
});
```

**My CSS**

```
   .hamburger div{
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.hamburger {
    width: 30px;
    display: none;
    margin: 3em 3em 3em 0;
    float: right;
    transition: all 0.75s 0.25s;
}

.one {
    width: 30px;
}

.two {
    width: 20px;
}

.three {
    width: 25px;
}

.hamburger:hover div {
    width: 30px;
}


.hamburger.closed {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .menu {
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        margin: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    .show {
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
}

    .headerbg {
        background: #000;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

If anyone maybe could lead me to a good example or even better help me out I would really appreciate it! Just came back after 2,5 years break from HTML/CSS as well.

Thanks for looking at the question!

Comment: As long as you do not state in clear the desired behavior your are drastically diminishing our chances to help you. You shouldn't be trying to *"create a class on a div"*. Instead, you should be *"opening a menu"*. Or closing/hiding it... etc. Adding classes is a means to and end. What's the end? Also please note adding your website as a live example doesn't really work, because when your issue will be fixed on the website, the question will lose relevance. Please add a working snippet ([mcve]) in the question itself, reproducing the problem and clearly stating the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of DOM elements seems to be vague. Let's break it down.

> I'm trying to create a class on a div and then delete it.

What is ***it*** here, what are you trying to delete? The class or the element?

> ..., because I'm adding a class to an ID instead of a Class.

That's not technically possible. You can't add a class to an id, nor can you add an id to a class. You can only add/remove/modify the `id` attribute of a DOM element and you can add/remove classes to the `className` property of a DOM element, referenced in markup by the `class` attribute.

To keep it short, using jQuery, you can select one or multiple elements by ID, by class, by attribute or by attribute value (in fact, by any valid CSS selector that matches the element), and you can apply the `.toggleClass()`, `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` methods (or any other jQuery methods) to that element (or to each element in the collection, if they are more than one).

To clarify things for you here's what your current code does:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  /* when all the DOM has finished building... */

  $(".hamburger").click(function(){
    /* do the following when an element with class "hamburger" is clicked: */

    $(".hamburger").toggleClass("closed");        
      /* toggle class `closed` on all elements with class "hamburger" 
         (not only on clicked one!) */

    $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
      // toggle class `show` on all elements with class "menu" 

    $("header").addClass('headerbg');
      // add class "headerbg" to all <header> elements in page
  });
 });
```

---

Addition, as per OP comment:

> *First I want to add the class `.headerbg` on the `<header>` when I click on the `.hamburger` class, then when I click on the `.hamburger` class again I want to delete/remove the class `.headerbg` for the `<header>`*

This will do it:

```js
/*
 * place the following inside an instance of 
 * $(document).ready(function(){...})
 */

$('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
  $('header').toggleClass('headerbg');
})
```

**Note:**

- `$(selector).click(function(){...})` is a shortcut for
  `$(selector).on('click', [child-selector,] function(){...})`. I personally recommend using the latter for all event binding functions to develop a consistent pattern of binding. It helps in the long run, when maintaining code. Also, it allows binding on elements that are not yet in DOM, by using the optional child selector argument. For example, if you wanted to do the binding before `.hamburger` was created in DOM, you could have, with the following syntax:

```js
$(window).on('click', '.hamburger', function(){
  $('header').toggleClass('headerbg');
})
```

The main difference is the first syntax binds an event listener on each and every instance of `.hamburger` it finds at the time the binding is done (`document.ready` in your case).
The second syntax binds only one event, on `window` object and evaluates at the moment of `click` if it was fired from inside an element with class `.hamburger` or not. This means that if you have 1k elements with class `.hamburger`, you don't bind an event on each of them (resulting in 1k listeners). Also, it has the great advantage that it will work on elements that are added to the page after the binding is done (because evaluation is done at the `click` event, not at the `ready` event.

To be even more precise and clear, there are two syntax choices here.

**1.** Choose between:

- `.click(function(){...})`
- `.on('click', function(){...})`

I ***always*** go for second, because it's consistent across all event listeners (it doesn't matter what I put as first argument, instead of `click` - also, it allows to bind on more than one event type at once: `.on('click tap swipe', function(){...})`)

**2.** Choose between

- `$(child-selector).on('click', function(){...})`
- `$(parent-selector).on('click', child-selector, function(){...})`.

If there is only one instance of `child-selector` and it's already in DOM at the time you do the binding, choose first. If there are more than one instances of `child-selector` and you want each one present inside `parent-selector`, use second.
Theoretically speaking, you want as few event listeners as possible, so instead of 2 listeners, one on each child is better to have a single listener on a parent.
Also, best practice is to use the smallest parent selector possible. For example, if you know all your `child-selector`s will always be contained in a div holding your content — say `$('#main')` — it's best to bind on that container rather than on `$('<body>')` or `$(window)`. This will make your code not be evaluated against a click event triggered outside of `$('#main')`, which in both theory and practice makes your page faster and lighter, for a better user experience.

Comment: First I want to add the class _.headerbg_ on the <header> when I click on the _.hamburger_ class, then when I click on the _.hamburger_ class again I  want to delete/remove the class _.headerbg_ for the <header>.

Comment: @MyName, updated with a clear explanation. (*I hope.*)

Answer (score 1):

in your `#header` you should toggle the `headerbg` not just adding it :

then your jquery must be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hamburger").click(function(){
    $(".hamburger").toggleClass("closed");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
    if($("#header").hasClass("headerbg")){
      $("#header").removeClass("headerbg");
    }
    else
    {
      $("#header").addClass("headerbg");
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Good rule of thumb...don't search dom more than once for same selector

Comment: Surely that `if(...) {...} else {...}` business would simplify to another `.toggleClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add the styles of the `ID` you should pass it through the `attr` function . like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hamburger").click(function(){
            $(".hamburger").toggleClass("closed");
            $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
            $("header").addClass('headerbg'); 
            $("header").attr('id','#header');
        });
    });
```

and you can delete it like this

```
$("header").attr('id','');
```

this way you can toggle it